# cant import code modules with vscode venv feature

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

VsCode provided venv creation feature. I tried it. Suppose, I have that project structure:

```
PJFOLDER
├── .venv/*
├── src/
│   └── inner_main.py
├── utils/
│   └── my_utils.py
└── outer_main.py
```

In both `inner_main.py` and `outer_main.py` I have imports of `my_utils.py` like that:

```
from utils import my_utils
```

Python Interpreter selected correctly (even automatically), basic type checker enabled, no errors. When I run `outer_main.py` via `Ctrl+F5` or just `Run Python file` - everything ok. But when I try to do the exact same thing with `inner_main.py` it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_utils'`.

I tried to type `python -m src.inner_main`, with activated venv ofc, and it worked!

Well, I thought it is because PATH variable, indeed, it has `path_to_project/PJFOLDER/.venv/Scripts/` but not my `PJFOLDER` explicitly.

I tried this code:

```
import os

path_var = os.environ["PATH"].split(";")
path_var.insert(0, os.getcwd())
os.environ["PATH"] = ";".join(path_var)
```

But it didn't help.

Can someone clarify this situation for me, please? How am I supposed to run inner code with inner imports preferably using default VSCode features like debugger and `Run Python file`? My project in early development and it can have multiple executable `.py` files and I don't want to type\select everything in terminal...

UPD 1:

Based on @Michael Butscher comment. I've created file `import_fix.py` with such code:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
```

This file lays in `.venv` folder. Since `sys.path` contains this folder, I can import it in any file in my project if I need. This file inserts current working directory in `sys.path` and I can use imports. Though it seems odd. Why doesn't `sys.path` contain cwd by default? Maybe there is a better solution? Maybe some setting in VSCode?

Comment: You can prepend the path to `PJFOLDER` to the list in `sys.path` to make the import work. In my opinion it would be better to place all possible main scripts in the project directory where `outer_main.py` is.

Comment: ```import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())``` You mean this? It works for me. But still looks clunky. Ye, I could store all possible main scripts in root folder, but it seems clunky too... I had no problem when I created venv by hands in root folder btw, but seeing so many unnecesary folders in root folder makes me anxious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is 3 ways.

1. Create `import_fix.py` file as I described above in UPD 1 and place it in `.venv` folder. You can run your code or debug.
2. Install Command Variable extenstion. Add new configuration to `launch.json`.

```
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Module", // you can use whatever name you like
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDotsNoExtension}",
            "justMyCode": false, // to debug my breakpoints
        }
```

Select it. Press `F5` or `Ctrl+F5` to run the debugger. This extension provides correct module name relative to current working directory. If you manage to make it yourselves without third-party extension, please, let me know.

3. Create `PJFOLDER/.venv/ANY-NON-EMPTY-NAME.pth` file with `../` content (or absolute/relative path to your PJFOLDER if you have different structure). This will include PJFOLDER in `sys.path` despite you using virtual environment.

First way is much simplier to create, but seems odd and you need to import unnecessary file whenever you need to import your code in others directories.

Second way is about debugging only. Though it's more convenient, strict, you don't need separate file to fix imports, you don't need that little overhead. If you want to run only, then you need to type `python -m folders_separated_by_dots.module_name`. I belive, there is a way to create custom default command in VSCode to run file as module by default (maybe via `tasks.json`...), but I'm not smart enough. Still, debugger is enough for me.

Third way is ... perfect? Default debugger works, `Run Python file` works. Still, need to create this file and it's content and, I guess, VSCode should do this by default, but it's better than install VSCode extension and add new debugger configuration and forget about `Run Python file` (though it's nothing crucial). **So, I guess, that's the answer for me.**

Though you can add useful info in comments.

UPD: 3rd way is not working with Python 3.12.2 when `.pth` file has empty name, [Read Security](https://docs.python.org/release/3.12.2/whatsnew/changelog.html#security)

Comment: Hi Eugene, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Ye, I know, but there is 2 days delay before I can mark my answer. 3 hours left :)

Answer (score 0):

You either need an `__init__.py` file in the utils folder or also `from ..utils import my_utils` should work, since the folder `utils` is not in the folder where you have `inner_main.py`, so you need to specify it.

And that's why when you run it from the main folder it's working.

Comment: Created empty `__init__.py` in `utils` folder. Didn't help. Relative import doesn't help either. `__init__.py` never works for me for some reason... I don't even know what it does 0_0

Comment: Theoretically `__init__.py` should index the folder. That's odd that is not working with the relative import though.

Comment: Have you tried both the relative import and the `__init__.py` together?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both together.

Comment: And what about running it from the terminal inside the src folder, does that work?

Comment: No, doesn't work =( Again, I created empty `__init__.py` inside `utils` foder. changed directory via `cd src` with venv activated. Tried both relative and not relative imports. Did I do everything correct?

Btw, check my UPD 1 in question. It seems better, I guess.

Comment: Yeath it seems everything should work. If it works with the new solution keep that I guess. My only other idea would have been to install utils as package in the venv using pip and a `setup.py`, but then you have to install it every time you change something in the package.